# How to style contents of textarea field with CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to style the contents of a textarea with CSS? I need to at the very least, insert more space after line breaks.

I want to basically have a new paragraph of text start within the textarea after every carriage return or line break.

Comment: Sounds more like a job for an actual rich text editor widget, of which there are many. (Usually based on `contenteditable`.)

Comment: In fact, `contenteditable` elements do in fact create new child `<div>`s when you press Enter. (And on Chrome, insert a `<br/>` with Shift-Enter.) So that might be what you want instead of a `textarea` if you don't want a whole library for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't style the content of a textarea. All you can do is insert more whitespace manually.
One approach is to replace single carriage returns with double ones

Comment: You mean manually entering double carriage returns right? Not dynamically creating a double carriage return within the textarea whenever ENTER is pressed?

Comment: Both are possible. You can add an event handler for the keyup event and convert single line breaks into double if you want it to happen automatically

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with either Javascript or PHP...

JS: `str.replace("\r\n", "<br />");`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

PHP: `str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", "whatyouaresearching", "number of replacements you want to make")`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

These are "String Replace" functions. So essentially what we are doing is searching a given string for a certain value and replacing it with another value.

Edit: Looks like I may have incorrectly assumed that the text area would interpret 
 correctly. OP, have you tried yet? If that doesn't work, then try using the HTML Entity Code as the replace value: `&#13;`

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp

Comment: Does this not pad the content received from the textarea, rather than the text being entered?

Comment: If you put brs into a textarea you will get <br> in the text

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood the question. I was actually looking to style the text within a textarea form field itself. Thanks for your help though, I do appreciate the time. :)